# ¿Qué es el "animalculismo"?

Tags: significado

En [ésta página](https://definiciona.com/animalculista/) he encontrado que **animalculista** es:

> El vocablo animalculista es de uso obsoleto y que (en medicina) que hace referencia una persona que profesa o es un especialista del animalculismo.

Pero no he encontrado la definición de **animalculismo** o **animalculista** en el diccionario de la RAE o en Wikipedia.

En [esta página](https://definiciona.com/animalculismo/), emparentada con la anterior, se define **animalculismo** como

> El termino animalculismo es de uso anticuado y que (en fisiología) nos refiere a un sistema disminuido que se puede suponer a los animales espermáticos que producen un embrión.

lo que no me parece nada claro. ¿Alguien puede arrojar alguna luz sobre el vocablo?

Comment: La palabra sale en un [diccionario de 1855](https://books.google.cl/books?id=1gRWU3imeiEC&pg=PA126&dq=animalculismo&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOwMzlkPTZAhVHWpAKHXZvBRwQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=animalculismo&f=false).

Answer (score 2):

Los animalculistas creían en los **animálculos**. La Wikipedia en inglés da *[animalcule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animalcule)* como un nombre primitivo para los microorganismos cuando apenas acababan de ser descubiertos.

Answer (score 2):

En [El País](https://elpais.com/elpais/2016/11/24/ciencia/1480013258_596607.html) he encontrado esto:

> Hasta mediados del siglo XIX, muchos científicos creían en el **animalculismo**, una teoría biológica que sostenía que **el espermatozoide albergaba ya una persona preformada y diminuta**.

Answer (score 1):

El sufijo latino *-culum* en latín podía tener un valor instrumental (*tentaculum*, instrumento para tantear, *speculum*, instrumento para mirar) o, como aquí, formar un diminutivo.

*Animalculum*, como tal diminutivo, ya sería utilizada de forma habitual por los latinos. Como concepto específico, tiene dos significados, ambos hipótesis para explicar las infecciones y la reproducción. Por ejemplo, Marco Terencio Varrón en su "Cuestiones de agricultura en tres libros" (alrededor del 30 a.E.C.) dice, sobre la ubicación de la finca:

> También, si hay lugares pantanosos, hay que colocarla en sentido
>   contrario, no sólo por las causas citadas sino también porque crecen
>   ciertos **animales minúsculos** que no pueden ser vistos por los ojos y
>   que penetran por el aire a través de boca y narices en el cuerpo y
>   causan graves enfermedades.

Aquí se ha traducido *animalculi* por "animales minúsculos".

Respecto a la reproducción, era un enigma (y, en cierto modo, sigue siéndolo) cómo de un animal podía salir otro, si no era creciendo. Así, se postulaba un *animalculum*, un animalillo perfectamente formado en miniatura que ya existía en el esperma (la hembra solo era la "tierra" donde se plantaba y crecía la semilla). Ya en la antigüedad se dieron cuenta de que eso solo llevaba la pregunta un lugar más allá porque, si existía un *animalculum* completo, también tenía que tener esperma, y dentro otro *animalculum*, y así sucesivamente. Total, que la explicación daba más problemas que el enigma que intentaba explicar.

Algo parecido, al hilo de esto, ocurría con la teoría psicológica del homúnculo mental para explicar la visión (también llamado "[teatro cartesiano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teatro_cartesiano)", aunque creo que sería más bien "cine"). ¿Quién ve las imágenes en mi mente? Pues un homúnculo que tengo dentro. Pero ¿cómo ve ese homúnculo? Pues tendrá otro homúnculo... y volvemos a tener el mismo problema.